# ReactJS - Should I use class method or external function

Tags: reactjs

Suppose I have a ReactJS component and want to call some custom function in it, is it better to have this function as a class method, or rather defined separately? (suppose that the function should be used only in this component)

```
class OnwComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.doubledNumber = this.doubledNumber.bind(this);
  }
  doubledNumber(num) {
    return num * 2;
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <p>{doubledNumber(10)} or {this.doubledNumber(10)}? Pros and cons?
    );
  }
}

function doubledNumber(num) {
  return num * 2;
}
```

Comment: "Better" in terms of what? IMO this comes down to preference. Since the function doesn't use `this`, there is no need to `.bind` it in the constructor or for it to be a class method.

Comment: The only two questions you need to ask yourself when deciding whether to use a Class or Functional component is 1) Do you need state and 2) Do you need lifecycle methods -- if you answer is yes to either of those then you should use a Class otherwise use a Function.

Comment: @riscarrott The question is not about class vs. functional components, please read it properly.

Comment: @FelixKling In whatever terms, mostly probably performance. I'm just thinking about creating some "best practices".

Comment: @user3696212 Ah, sorry -- in that case yes, I'd say it's more idiomatic JS to  use methods rather than separate functions and it would allow sub classes (granted not popular in the React community) to override them.

Comment: Yeah, it's a style preference, but I would argue that any function that doesn't need a 'this' should just be an independent function - makes the intent a lot clearer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is generally just a style preference.

Having said that, ESlint has exactly this rule: [class-methods-use-this](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/class-methods-use-this):

> If a class method does not use this, it can safely be made a static
>   function.

Also, one of the most popular React style guides (airbnb) has this rule enabled by default. So, in terms of best practices I would say: move `doubledNumber` function out of the class.

In the [discussion related to implementing this rule](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/5139) in eslint, they talk about performance considerations too:

> This rule is stylistic, but has performance implications. If a
>   function is not using this, it is unnecessarily copied whenever a new
>   instance of the class is created.

Comment: Thank you, this is valuable.

Comment: how about functional components? can I move doubledNumber outside of the function?

Answer (score 1):

**It depends**.

If the function is related to the component logic itself and used only there, I'd leave it as a component method.

Otherwise:

- If the function represents a solution to a generic programming common problem, I'd move it in a helper component, import the helper component in your React component and use it.
- If the function is related to a specific business logic, I'd move it inside a service component, that holds the feature business logic, import the service component in your React component and use it.

So, this is primary an opinion based question. Based on your project set-up and the method logic, you need to make the final decision.